# Simulate keypress using jQuery and fire oninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

Reacts TestUtils.simulate causes the oninput function to fire as well. However, due to some restrictions, I am not able to use that.

Is there any way of simulating, and thereby causing the oninput function to fire, a kerypress using jQuery?

Comment: Yes there is, see the trigger method

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<fieldset>
<label for="target">Type Something:</label>
<input id="target" type="text">
</fieldset>
</form>
<button id="other">
 Trigger the handler
</button>
  <script src="/resources/events.js"></script>

  <script>
   var xTriggered = 0;
   $( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {
   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
     }
   xTriggered++;
  var msg = "Handler for .keypress() called " + xTriggered + " time(s).";
  console.log( msg, "html" );
  console.log( event );
 });

 $( "#other" ).click(function() {
 $( "#target" ).keypress();
 });
</script>
```